# Tool to find duplicate keys and value in properties file

Tags: java, internationalization

is there a tool that tells me redundant keys and values that are there in my one or many properties file.

Comment: Rather than a tool, you may want to consider an integration test. It sounds weird, but I've written one (with JUnit) to help prevent an issue with properties files and our 3rd party translation staff.

Comment: Simple and easy way..get codePro AnalytiX from google, its a eclipse plugin. You can audit your code, it will find all the duplicate key in properties file.

Comment: i found that couple of months back.Thanks for your comment :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an Ant task, RscBundleCheck, that checks for the existence of duplicate keys in a set of resource files:

http://rscbundlecheck.sourceforge.net/

This would be simple way to integrate checking for duplicate properties into your build process.

Answer (score 5):

```
/**
 *  Purpose:  Properties doesn't detect duplicate keys.  So this exists.
 *  @author shaned
 */
package com.naehas.tests.configs;

import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class NaehasProperties extends Properties
{
   private static final long   serialVersionUID = 1L;

   private static final Logger log              = Logger.getLogger(NaehasProperties.class);

   public NaehasProperties()
   {
      super();
   }

   /**
    * @param defaults
    */
   public NaehasProperties(Properties defaults)
   {
      super(defaults);
   }

   /**
    * Overriding the HastTable put() so we can check for duplicates
    * 
    */
   public synchronized Object put(Object key, Object value)
   {
      // Have we seen this key before?
      //
      if (get(key) != null)
      {
         StringBuffer message = new StringBuffer("Duplicate key found: " + key + " with value: " + value);
         message.append(". Original value is: " + (String) get(key));

         log.error(message.toString());

         // Setting key to null will generate an exception and cause an exit.
         // Can not change the signature by adding a throws as it's not compatible
         // with HashTables put().
         //
         // If you commented out this line, you will see all the occurrences of the duplicate key
         // as the put will overwrite the past encounter.
         //
         key = null;
      }

      return super.put(key, value);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is an existing tool, but you should be able to write a short java program, or script in a language you are comfortable with that should do this in no time.  Then you would also have it for future use.

A quick google search yielded the following http://www.javanb.com/netbeans/1/19793.html

this has a gui tool and a script that will do it.

Comment: Me too found it, but seems to be too old

Comment: Too old? What to you mean by that? If it worked then, it will work now. Or did the properties file format change sometime?

Answer (score 1):

On Netbeans there is a [sort line tools](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/45925/sort-line-tools) plugin, which has the option to remove duplicates. Works perfectly if properties are one lined.

What is more, sorting the properties makes this file more readible.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easiest just to write one: For each file, and for each property in that file, put the property key/value pair into a Map, but only after ensuring that the key is not already in the Map.  If it is, print out the file name, the key, and the two values.

Comment: Ya, i am writing one in groovy.But its better to reuse and create,if we have one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an IDE you might find a good tool among their plugins/features.

Eclipse has a ResourceBundle Editor plugin which manages properties files:

http://www.eclipseplugincentral.com/Web_Links-index-req-viewlink-cid-331.html

IntelliJ IDEA 8 and higher is also able to manage properties files and check for duplicate entries.

Answer (score 0):

There are two nice tools that I use

1. **unival** npm package: this is a command line tool to detect duplicate keys, values or lines.

   npm command to install the package: `npm i unival`

   Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/unival
2. **unival** extension: if you use vscode, this is a extremely helpful extension to detect duplicates on the fly.