# How to know whether a property exists or not in a property file?

Tags: java

How to know whether a property exists or not in a property file in java?

Answer (score 12):

According to http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html, `getProperty()` returns `null` if the property was not found. You could also call `propertyNames()` or `stringPropertyNames()` and look to see whether the property name of interest is in the returned set.

Answer (score 11):

Yet another alternative is to exploit the fact the `Properties extends Hashtable<Object,Object>` and use `containsKey`.

Comment: That's not working for me in Java8 via groovy.  I'm not sure it would work in pure java either

Answer (score 5):

Just load the properties file and then try to get the desired property.

```
public String getProperty(String key)
```

> Searches for the property with the specified key in this property list. If the key is not found in this property list, the default property list, and its defaults, recursively, are then checked. **The method returns null if the property is not found.**

- http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#getProperty(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 4):

You can also call `getProperty(String key, String defaultValue)` and check if the return value is the `defaultValue`.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#getProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

Comment: What if the property was set to default value? This is not a safe approach.

Comment: You can set `defaultValue` to a value that is not valid in the particular domain, e,g.: `### PLACEHOLDER ###`

Answer (score 2):

You can use hasProperty

```
AllValues.hasProperty("childList")
```

Comment: I'm not seeing that method in my debugger or the javadoc for 7 or 8. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check that at the start of program you can do the following:

1. Create a class `VerifiedProperties` that extends `Properties`
2. Add all properties as fields of this class as `public final int/String/boolean/etc...`
3. Add `private final String propertyNotValid="Property not valid"` String to this class
4. Add `private final String propertyNotFound="Property not found"` String to this class
5. Override `getProperty()` method from Properties class.
6. You can add `@Deprecated` tag to suggest usage of the fields. It is impossible to hide this method because it is public in Properties class.
7. Initialize all fields in the constructor using `getProperty()` method or dedicated for type (look examples below)

Example methods that takes care of different property types:

> ```
> @Override
> @Deprecated
> /*
>  Deprecated annotation added to suggest usage of the fields.
>  */
> public final String getProperty(String key)
> {
>     String propertyValue = super.getProperty(key);
>     if (propertyValue != null)
>     {
>         return propertyValue;
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         throw new NoSuchFieldError(this.propertyNotFound + " " + key);
>     }
> }
> private int getIntegerProperty(String key)
> {
>     String propertyValue = this.getProperty(key);
>     try
>     {
>         int propertyIntValue = Integer.parseInt(propertyValue);
>         return propertyIntValue;
>     }
>     catch (NumberFormatException e)
>     {
>         throw new NumberFormatException(this.propertyNotValid + " " + key);
>     }
> }
> private boolean getBooleanProperty(String key)
> {
>     String propertyValue = this.getProperty(key);
>     try
>     {
>         boolean propertyBooleanValue = Boolean.parseBoolean(propertyValue);
>         return propertyBooleanValue;
>     }
>     catch (NumberFormatException e)
>     {
>         throw new NumberFormatException(this.propertyNotValid + " " + key);
>     }
> }
> private long getLongProperty(String key)
> {
>     String propertyValue = this.getProperty(key);
>     try
>     {
>         long propertyLongValue = Long.parseLong(propertyValue);
>         return propertyLongValue;
>     }
>     catch (NumberFormatException e)
>     {
>         throw new NumberFormatException(this.propertyNotValid + " " + key);
>     }
> }
> ```

Then you can create somewhere:

> public static VerifiedProperties properties;

and use the properties that you need as `properties.myProperty`

### Advantages:

- you have full control over properties which includes exception handling and null checking
- If property does not exist or is in incorrect format, you will have the information at the initialization of the program
- You don't need to worry about parsing properties to different types than String in your code.
- You can add validators to your `String` properties
- You can easily refactor property name
- If you are using external property file that can be modified by the user outside of your application, if provided change is incorrect or there are fields missing your program will not start.

### Disadvantages:

- For each property besides adding value to `*.properties` file you need to create field and assign value in the constructor. If you have a lot of properties then this file can look unpleasant.

### Hints:

- it is easier to mantain the file if you keep the same name for the field as in properties file.
- (Netbeans) you can `Toggle Rectangular Selection` to add `public final String` and similar to many lines at once.
- (Netbeans) to keep `*.properties` file clean you can use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779196/tool-to-find-duplicate-keys-and-value-in-properties-file/24449076#24449076).

Answer (score 1):

The answer by crazyscot is now outdated. According to the new [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29), the property will just get created if it doesn't exist,

> "If there is no current set of system properties, a set of system properties is first created and initialized in the same manner as for the getProperties method".

Answer (score -1):

Here is some trick how to find out is some file (not mandatory property file) exists in class path

```
public class FileUtil {
    public static boolean isFileExists(String fileName){
         return null != FileUtil.class.getResourceAsStream(fileName);
    }
}
```

Sure it not always works as long it depends on class loading aspects